# Is there any way to export a Custom Word Ribbon with custom macros as an Add-in?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, excel-addins, ribbonx

I've seen Excel Add-in's (XLAM) that can be installed on other computers. You install it and a custom Ribbon appears, with new buttons that trigger custom macros.
I've made some macros on Word, created a custom Ribbon tab with buttons through XML, everything works just fine but I can't manage to export it so I can install it on other computers.
Any thoughts?

Comment: Save it as a template (.dotm) and place that file into the other computers' STARTUP folder. Another option is to convert it to Vsto.

Comment: Where did you store the macros? Don't use normal.dotm for this! This file can get overwritten anytime - and then everything you programmed is lost. Save it, as Raymond said, as another template (dotm) - you find the STARTUP-Folder by pasting `%appdata%\microsoft\word\STARTUP` in the "address" field of explorer.